# Setting ANDROID_HOME variable globally on PhpStorm / WebStorm on Linux

Tags: react-native, phpstorm, android-settings

PhpStorm / Webstorm on Linux didn't mentioned the System-ENV Variables. 
So even if you have export ANDROID_HOME in your .bashrc or .bash_profiles, this Variable is not usable in PhpStorm.

Currently I need it to run react-native packager:

`"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android"`

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

So what is the easiest way to fix this globally and permanent for the Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are two ways.**

First (but not best) is to set the Enviroment-Variable for each Script-Entry in the `Edit Run/Debug Configuration` settings:

[image]

Better way is to set it globally per Project. To do this, do the following steps:

1. Open your Project
2. Browse to the /android Directory in your Project
3. Create a file named: `local.properties`
4. Insert `sdk.dir=<pathToYourAndroidSDKgoesHere>`

Answer (score 1):

When being launched from desktop/System menu, PhpStorm only sees environment variables configured in `~/.profile` (login shell), but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `~/.bashhrc`).
Possible workarounds:

- Workaround 1: make required variables available in a login shell (i.e. for bash, move them from `.bashrc` to `.bash_profile`).
- Workaround 2: run IDE from a terminal, via `bin/phpstorm.sh`
- Workaround 3: edit the desktop launcher and set command to `/bin/bash -l -i -c "/path/to/phpstorm.sh"`

see also  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589

And one more thing to check: make sure that **Include parent environment variables** checkbox is ticked in your **Run** configuration, **Environment variables** dialog

Comment: Thats work not for me, if I start phpstorm with jetbrains-toolbox.